# Get the nearest date to specific from the list of dates?

Tags: java, java-8

I have two date fields in Temp class say validFromDate and asOfDate. I have List with me. I need to set the flag whihc is one of the class attributes to true for the record whose validFromDate is closest to asOfDate

Ex.

```
List<temp> {
    Temp1:
        asOfDate: 2018-01-04
        validFrom: 2018-01-01
    Temp2:
        asOfDate: 2018-01-04
        validFrom: 2018-01-02
    Temp3:
        asOfDate: 2018-01-04
        validFrom: 2018-01-03
}
```

o/p should be Temp3 as this validFrom is nearest to asOfdate. I will set the flag to true for this Temp2

How can I achieve this using Java 8 streams?

Comment: last one should be `Temp3`?

Comment: Have you tried any code yet?

Comment: private Limit getClosestApplicableLimit(List<Limit> limitList, LocalDate asOfDate) {
        LocalDate currentNearestDate = null;
        for (Limit limit : limitList) {
            if (limit.getValidFrom().isBefore(asOfDate) && (currentNearestDate == null || limit.getValidFrom().isAfter(currentNearestDate))) {
                currentNearestDate = limit.getValidFrom();
                applicableLimit = limit;
            }
        }

        return applicableLimit;
    }

Comment: I tried above code. But want to know how to do in java streams

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  temp.stream()
      .map(x -> new SimpleEntry<>(x, ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(x.getAsOfDate(), x.getValidFrom())))
      .min(Comparator.comparingLong(Entry::getValue))
      .map(Entry::getKey)
      .orElse(...);
```

Or simpler:

```
test.stream()
    .min(Comparator.comparingLong(x -> ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(x.asOfDate , x.validFrom)));
```

Comment: Can I update the field value in above code and return  the list instead of single object

Comment: @Sahil what would the list contain?

Comment: Input: List<Temp> : {temp1, validFrom, asOfDate, applicable}...applicable flag should be updated to true for the nearest validFrom date or else false. Finally the list should be updated with applicable flag true or false based on above logic

Comment: @Sahil you make no sense, you want to `sort` the `List` based on that difference?

Comment: I dont want to sort the list. I want to find the validFrom date nearest to asOfDate and update that records flag to true or else false and return the updated list

Comment: @Sahil nearest compared to what? just the nearest single one? in such case you *do* need to sort: `List<Test> result = test.stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparingLong(x -> ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(x.asOfDate, x.validFrom)))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()); result.get(0).setWhateverFlagYouWant`

Comment: nearest to asOfDate. asOfDate is same for all the records of the list. I just want to find the nearest validFromdate to asOfDate record and update its applicable flag to false.Remaining records applicable flag should be set to fase

Comment: @Sahil in this case you need to sort first and then update the flag: `List<Test> result = test.stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparingLong(x -> ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(x.asOfDate, x.validFrom)))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()); Spliterator<Test> sp = result.stream().spliterator();
        sp.tryAdvance(x -> x.setWhatEverFlag(true));
        sp.forEachRemaining(x -> x.setWhatEverFlar(false));
        `

Comment: I think there might be more logic required as requirement is slightly changes. If nearest validFrom date to asOfDate returns multiple records then , next we have to get neares createdDate to asOfDate record. Any insight on this?

Comment: @Sahil no! starting coding yourself from here

Comment: yea sure @Eugene, Thanks a lot

Comment: This worked for me as I write my custom comaparator :List<Temp> applicableTemps = tempList.stream()
                .sorted(sortApplicableTemps)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        Spliterator<Temp> spTempIterator = temp.stream().spliterator();
        spTempIterator.tryAdvance(temp -> temp.setApplicable(Boolean.TRUE));
        spLimitIterator.forEachRemaining(temp-> temp.setApplicable(Boolean.FALSE));

Comment: @Sahil in case Ive helped you, you can accept my answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ChronoUnit.DAYS.between` to calculate the number of days between the dates, then use [`Stream.min`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/?java/util/stream/Stream.html) to get the lowest value:

```
Optional<MyClass> shortestDate = myList.stream()
    .min(
        Comparator.comparingLong(
            item -> ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(item.asOfDate(), item.validFrom())
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

We can try sorting your list based on the absolute difference between the `asOfDate` and the `validFrom` date, then take the first element from the sorted list.  Something like this:

```
list.sort((Temp t1, Temp t2)
    ->Long.compare(Math.abs(t1.getAsOfDate().getTime() - t1.getValidFrom().getTime()),
        Math.abs(t2.getAsOfDate().getTime() - t2.getValidFrom().getTime())));
System.out.println(list.get(0));
```

This assumes that your dates are the old school pre Java 8 `java.util.Date` class.  If not, my code would have to change.  This also assumes that you are OK with changing the order of the list.

Follow the demo link below which shows that the above lambda sort in fact works on a small set of sample data.

### Demo

**Edit:**

If you don't want to alter the original list, but instead want to just update the single matching `Temp` element, then you can make a copy of the list and then sort the copy:

```
List<Temp> copy = new ArrayList<>(list);
// sort copy, per above
// then update the original list
Temp match = copy.get(0);
int index = list.indexOf(match);
list.get(index).setFlag(true);
```